# Access Denied for Admin User

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I've been trying to add a policy to my admin area of my web app, and have added my admin user and the admin role to both my `AspNetUsers`, `AspNetRoles` and `AspNetUserRoles` tables, however I cannot verify that the user I'm signed is as is an admin.

`AspNetUsers` table

```
Id    |    UserName    |    NormalizedUserName    |    Email               |    NormalizedEmail
_______________________________________________________________________________________________
123   |    WebAdmin    |    WEBADMIN              |    admin@mysite.com    |    ADMIN@MYSITE.COM
```

`AspNetRoles` Table

```
Id    |    Name    |    NormalizedName
_______________________________________
123   |    Admin   |    ADMIN
_______________________________________
321   |    User    |    USER
```

`AspNetUserRoles` table

```
UserId    |    RoleId
______________________
123       |    123
```

I've included the `Identity` in the `ConfirgureServices` of my `Startup` class

```
/// <summary>
/// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="services">Services to configure</param>
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Regular Cookie Policy stuff
    services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
    {
        // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
        options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
        options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
    });

    // Mailing service setup
    services.AddScoped<SmtpClient>((serviceProvider) =>
    {
        return new SmtpClient
        {
            Host = this.Configuration.GetValue<string>("Email:Smtp:Host"),
            Port = this.Configuration.GetValue<int>("Email:Smtp:Port"),
            UseDefaultCredentials = false,
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential(
                    this.Configuration.GetValue<string>("Email:Smtp:Username"), 
                    this.Configuration.GetValue<string>("Email:Smtp:Password")),
            EnableSsl = true
        };
    });

    // Connect to the Database
    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(this.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
    services.AddDbContext<WebSiteContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(this.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

    // Identity Stuff
    services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()
        .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

    // Configure Authorization
    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

    // Authorization
    services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("RequireAdminRole", policy => policy.RequireRole("Admin"));
    });
}
```

I use all of these in my `Configure` Method as well

```
/// <summary>
/// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="app">App being configured</param>
/// <param name="env">Environment the app is running in</param>
/// <param name="context">Injected <see cref="DbContext"/></param>
/// <param name="userManager">Injected <see cref="UserManager{TUser}"/></param>
/// <param name="roleManager">Injected <see cref="RoleManager{TRole}"/></param>
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ApplicationDbContext context, UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager, RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    // Set up the usings
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseCookiePolicy();
    app.UseAuthentication();

    // Seed the Database on Startup
    Seeder.SeedDb(context, userManager, roleManager);

    // Use MVC
    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "areas",
            template: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
}
```

`ManageController` Controller for my admin portion has the `Authorize` Declaration

```
/// <summary>
/// ManageController - Controller for Managing Admin Stuff
/// </summary>
[Area("admin")]
[Route("admin/[controller]")]
[Authorize(Policy = "RequireAdminRole")]
public class ManageController : Controller
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Private instance of the <see cref="EmailViewModel"/> class
    /// </summary>
    private EmailViewModel emailViewModel;
    private SmtpClient smtpClient;

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="ManageController"/> class
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="smtpClient"></param>
    public ManageController(SmtpClient smtpClient)
    {
        this.smtpClient = smtpClient;
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// HomePage for the admin management area
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

However, when I sign in as WebAdmin and navigate to my `admin/Manage` area, I get the following error:

> Access Denied - You do not have access to this resource

Is there something that I'm missing when checking roles in NET Core?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this issue. The issue lies in configuring the Identity service. I needed to use `AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()` instead of `AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()`

I changed

```
// Identity Stuff
services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()
    .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

To

```
// Identity Stuff
services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
    .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

And it worked.

Comment: What version of `ASP.NET Core Identity` are you using? Because with version 2.2.0, you don't even need that line `.AddRoles<IdentityRole>()`.

Comment: I'm using 2.1 but I should probably go with 2.2 in the future. Thanks for the FYI

Comment: Im using ApplicaitonUser but am always getting access denied :-( @jDave1984 any ideas.